# Cannot download article using newspaper3k

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-newspaper

I have even tried the commands in [pypi.org](https://pypi.org/project/newspaper3k/) but no article is getting downloaded.

```
from newspaper import Article

url = 'http://fox13now.com/2013/12/30/new-year-new-laws-obamacare-pot-guns-and-drones/'
article = Article(url)
article.download()
article.html
```

article.html only gives empty sting ' '. when i try article.parse() it gives error *

> You must `download()` an article first!

I have tried workaround

```
while article.download_state == ArticleDownloadState.NOT_STARTED:
    # Raise exception if article download state does not change after 10 seconds
    if slept > 9:
        raise ArticleException('Download never started')
    sleep(1)
    slept += 1
```

still unable to solve the issue.

Comment: I was able to download and parse the article using the `newspaper` library for Python 3.6. If the HTML is coming up blank, there is some issue with the request.

Comment: its not working for me and i cannot find a solution

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you have to clean up the link, e.g. from a RSS feed.

The urlparse python library can be used for Google Alerts.

Example

```
google_url = 'https://www.google.com/url?rct=j&sa=t&url=https://www.timesnownews.com/international/article/european-union-chief-donald-tusk-lashes-out-at-donald-trump-stance-on-europe/311933&ct=ga&cd=CAIyHDlhZGYyMmM4NzAwYzNlZDc6Y28udWs6ZW46R0I&usg=AFQjCNHrsEaxxjXvWB3wM_1aRjNg6aeZvw'
```

Get variable after url=

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs
url = urlparse(google_url)
print (parse_qs(url.query)['url'][0])
```

Moreover, also mind that the output is overwritten if different not separately assigned.

The output will only include article.text during testing your script:

```
article = Article('https://www.google.com/url?rct=j&sa=t&url=https://www.timesnownews.com/international/article/european-union-chief-donald-tusk-lashes-out-at-donald-trump-stance-on-europe/311933&ct=ga&cd=CAIyHDlhZGYyMmM4NzAwYzNlZDc6Y28udWs6ZW46R0I&usg=AFQjCNHrsEaxxjXvWB3wM_1aRjNg6aeZvw')
article.download()
article.parse()
article.top_image
article.text
```

This works during testing your script:

```
top_image = article.top_image
text = article.text
print (top_image, text)
```